# What mortar should be used for flagstone?

Tags: mortar, pavers

I once read about a mortar that starts as a powder I could put in between my flagstones, and then just wet it down and it would harden in place.

Do you know what this product is?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a caveat:

> We only use this dry grouting method with freshly buttered joints, where find that there is sufficient moisture from the 'proper' mortar to initiate setting of the dry mix. Dry mix into dry joints rarely, if ever, produces a good joint

From http://www.pavingexpert.com/pointing.htm#dry

A basic dry mix is 4:1 sand to cement.  That's by volume, not weight.  I'd try to find a fine sand, and preferably sharp cornered.

You may be able to find a premix at your patio/garden center.

The problem here is that all cement compounds require a significant amount of water to cure, and your joints will need water from the bottom as well as the top.  You might be better off using a wet mix and just taking the time to apply it carefully.

Answer (score 1):

No special mix is required. It is a technique called dry grouting.

To use this the surface MUST be dry and done during a sunny day.

- The 4:1 mortar mixture is mixed dry - no water is added at all, and it is essential that the sands and cement are thoroughly mixed together in the dry state before scattering onto the dry paving surface, and then using a soft brush to sweep the mix into the joints.
- Some people will try to fine mist of water (with like some kind of plant bed sprinkler system mist spray nozzle) over the area but this can cause splashes in the joins.
- Concrete inherently absorbs moisture from the air and the grout will harden over time.

You must realise though that this is rarely used because the outcome is not very pretty, using stains in the mix can cause stains on your flagstones too and is really only used straight after your flagstones are put down or there is enough ground moisture to help the mix set.

Answer (score 1):

I have used 
[Polymeric Sand](http://www.sakrete.com/products/detail.cfm/prod_alias/Paver-Set-Polymeric-Sand) in this way.

For pavers, you sweep it into the joints, wet it and it hardens in place.

This has worked well to prevent weed growth and washout from water, but it **does not** obstruct ants from tunneling. They seem just as capable of prying this glue/sand apart as regular sand.