# Flagstone joint filler options

Tags: patio, pavers

[image]

What should  I use to fill these  flagstones joints? Joint size is between 1-4". Is mortar my best option? Will polymeric sand work with these huge gaps?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What mortar should be used for flagstone?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/18173/what-mortar-should-be-used-for-flagstone)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Those gaps are indeed huge.  What's the  traffic on this going to be like? What's underneath the flagstones?

Comment: Hi Daniel. Lots of traffic. Its ground underneath.

Comment: Is it flagstone or a concrete poured walkway molding? Mortar will crack and break in gaps that large. The best option may be to use a sand filler. Wet it down, sand fill and sweep, wet that down. Repeat until it is the desired height. You could even add a little Portland cement to the sand, just to help keep it together. Paver sand is what I would use, not play sand.

Comment: Not sure i think its flagstone because the are all diff size

Comment: It looks like precast concrete walkway pavers.